# Delete rows from a ndarray in python

Tags: indexing, boolean

I have a 2D - array `A`, which contains the x and y coordinates of points

```
array([[ 0,  0],
       [ 0,  0],
       [ 0,  0],
       [ 3,  4],
       [ 4,  1],
       [ 5, 10],
       [ 9,  7]])
```

as you can see the point `( 0 , 0 )` appears more often.

I want to delete this point so that the array looks like this:

```
array([[ 3,  4],
       [ 4,  1],
       [ 5, 10],
       [ 9,  7]])
```

Since the array in real is very huge, it is very important to do this without for loops, otherwise it takes very long.

I'm new to python but i'm used to matlab, where I can solve it very easily with:

```
A (A(:,1) == 0 & A(:,2) == 0, :) = []
```

I thought it is almost the same or very similar in python, but I can't figure it out - am totally stuck. Errors like "use a.any()/all()" or "ufunc "bitwise_and" not supported for the input types" appear and I don't know what I should change.

Comment: hi thx for ur answer but that did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically what you are doing in MATLAB is not deleting elements from `A`.  What you are actually doing is creating a new array that lacks the elements of A.  It is equivalent to:

```
>> A = A (A(:,1) ~= 0 | A(:,2) ~= 0, :);
```

You can do exactly the same thing in numpy:

```
>>> a = a[(a[:,0] != 0) | (a[:,1] != 0), :]
```

However, thanks to numpy's automatic broadcasting, you can make this simpler:

```
>>> a = a[(a != [0, 0]).any(1)]
```

This will work for any target array so long as it has the same number of columns as `a`.

Comment: sorry but can you explain me the "1" in any() very quick?
the docs state: "return True if any element of the iterable is true"
but honestly I'm not certain about the meaning in the expression you posted

Comment: @Christoph: You are looking at python's `any` function.  But the `foo.any(bar)` (or `(foo).any(bar)`) is the `any` *method*, in this case the `ndarray.any` method ( https://docs.scipy.org/doc//numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.any.html ).  This is similar to calling `numpy.any(A, 1)`.  The `1` is the `axis` argument, it determines what axis the `any` operation is applied across (by default it uses a flattened version of the array).